# Blank screen with AMD Sapphire RX 580 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, gpu

To have a new **AMD Sapphire RX 580 Nitro** up and running on a fresh Ubuntu 16.04.3 64bit, I have followed AMD [instructions](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Installation-Instructions-for-amdgpu-Graphics-Stacks.aspx) and installed their (default) `amdgpu-pro 17.50`.

It seems to be installed:

```
# dpkg -l amdgpu-pro
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  amdgpu-pro     17.50-511655 amd64        Meta package to install amdgpu Pr
```

But after reboot,  while I plugged the monitor to the GPU instead of the motherboard socket DVI, the screen is blank.

And the GPU not recognized:

```
# lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0412] (rev 06)
```

Ubuntu Wiki [says](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver):

> Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and newer: for some most recent graphics cards (R9
> 285, R9 380/380X, R9 M395X, R9 Nano/Fury/FuryX, RX 460/470/480, RX
> 550/560/570/580...) and APUs (Carrizo, Stoney), the open-source AMDGPU
> driver is enabled by default. For Ubuntu 16.04 LTS AMDGPU-Pro hybrid
> driver is also available to download here

The GPU is fixed the slot on which I had an Nvidia driver previously with no issues. Also, I see that the light on the GPU is on but the fans do not rotate.

My ubuntu-desktop is `gnome-fallback`, in case that's relevant.

What can be wrong here? How can I troubleshoot/fix this?
Really appreciate your help. This problem bugs me for hours.

**UPDATE:**
Just figured that AMD [confirms](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-Compatibility-Advisory-with-Ubuntu-16.04.2-and-16.04.3.aspx) this problem:

> Installation of AMDGPU-PRO drivers on Ubuntu 16.04.3 will likely
> result in issues, such as black screen hang or defaulting to a lower
> graphics mode without acceleration.  This also applies to Ubuntu
> 16.04.2 users who have been upgraded to 16.04.3.

but oddly does not offer any solution!

Answer (score 0):

If you use 17.50 version of the driver, it isn't your fault, I'm on 17.10 testing with a RX 580 sapphire and it do that.
So download an old driver version (for me 17.10 (of the driver) work).

Comment: Interesting! I'm using  17.40 which is the default for download. Where can I get older versions?

Comment: you can't get older version > than 15.11 but isn't working on 17.10, I ask the support for 16.40 (I'm waiting for the answer) (the page isn't updated)

Answer (score -1):

It's just the splash sscreen.

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

And then

```
sudo apt-get remove lightdm
```

Reboot and you're good to go.